# I need help to find the asymptotic expansion of the following integral as n approaches infinity.

Tags: asymptotics

$
I(n) =\int^\infty_0e^{-\lambda t-n\ln t}\int^\infty_{-\infty}e^{-s^2/2}e^{-i(s/\sigma)\ln t}e^{i(s/\sigma)\ln n}/\Gamma(1+is/\sigma) dsdt
$

as $n\rightarrow \infty$, $\lambda >0$ . This is what I did.

Change variables $t=nz$, so $dt=ndz$.  Thus $\ln t=\ln n +\ln z$ and
\begin{align}
&e^{- \lambda t-n \ln( t)} =n^{-n}e^{-n(\lambda z+\ln z)}=n^{-n}e^{-n\xi(z)}\\
e^{-(is/\sigma)\ln t} &=e^{-(is/\sigma)\ln n}e^{-(is/\sigma)\ln z}
\end{align}
where $\xi(z)=\lambda z+\ln z$.  With this transformation,
\begin{align}
I(n) &=nn^{-n}\int^\infty_0e^{-n\xi(z)}h(z)dz\\
h(z)= &\int^\infty_{-\infty}e^{-s^2/2}e^{-i(s/\sigma)\ln z}/\Gamma(1+is/\sigma)ds
 \end{align}

Thusit is in the form for  Laplace's approximation. The problem  is, the critical point $z_0=-1/\lambda$ of $\xi(z)$ does not lie in $(0,\infty)$.

So, I don't think this is the right approach.  Any ideas, I welcome.